# Which platform should I use to develop a multiplayer card game?

Tags: c#, java, wpf, silverlight

I want to make a multiplayer card game for Facebook which will work on a client-server design: A server outside Facebook that will host the game and hold all the logic, and a client-side app which will be implemented in Facebook so users from Facebook can play and compete each other and gain higher scores.

I want animation of moving cards (for example the animation like in the texas hold'm poker game).

What technologies do you recommend using for both the client and server sides of this?

Is WPF something I can use here? Or do I need to use Silverlight (which, I understand, has only a subset of the features of WPF)?

Should I use Java Applet and make something in Swing? Do I have a better way to implement it all in Java?

Comment: Keep is simple. Avoid Silverlight/Applets/Flash unless that really is "the best" for your target audience -- Flash is *by far* the most common across desktop browsers but it is still another dependency to deal with. With the client-server setup, the client really is just a "dumb interface" and should be simple to implement if the server connectivity is there and kept to nice clean common-denominator. The client is (or should) also (be) *independent* of the server/server-side language. Happy coding.

Comment: @pst , why to avoid Silverlight ? isn't it better for good animation and smoothy look that PHP/JS/jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd personally opt for using canvas (the new HTML5 element) for the client side if facebook allows it. True, it's not supported everywhere but Java applets are dying out and I can see silverlight and flash going the same way.

If you want to use Java to do it, you can check out GWT and the GWT-canvas plugin. It'll let you write everything in Java but it'll compile down to Javascript (with the added bonus that browsers that don't support HTML5 will fall back to using a plugin.)

In terms of the server side logic, it doesn't really matter what you implement it in, just choose what you feel comfortable with and go with it (Java servlets, Php, ASP.NET, all will be up for the job.)

Comment: @berry120, it's also important to hold some database for users scores, what do you recommand for that? is WPF only for win apps so for web I need to use asp.net or silverlight ?

Comment: I'd use something like MySQL or PostgreSQL. Especially since this is a final year project, experience with either of those (especially the former) would be a plus. Dealing with a MySQL database from PHP is a doddle, and while it's a bit more involved with Java servlets it's certainly very do-able - if you haven't used JDBC connectors already I'd give it a shot. It's a good thing to have experience in!

Comment: @berry120, if you had to develop the server side would you use Java + JDBC for DB, or C# with MySQL or am I mixing ?

Comment: JDBC stands for Java database connectivity, it's not a type of database but the API you use for connecting to databases such as MySQL. I'd personally opt for Java and MySQL, but that's at least partly because that's what I'm most experienced in using and thus could get results with the fastest :-)

Comment: @berry120, Do you think it would be good to develop the server side with JAVA + MySQL and the Client side in Silverlight?

Comment: That sounds fine to me. Personally I wouldn't opt for using Silverlight, but that's just based purely on my preferences. Silverlight will do all that you need it to.

Comment: @berry120, why wouldn't you use Silverlight?

Comment: Personally (others may disagree) I'm not convinced of its future on the web front. True it has got some stuff to offer that HTML5 hasn't, but for the most part I expect to see HTML5 take it over, much like it will for flash.

Comment: @berry120, how come you think HTML5 will be the future ? and not Silverlight ?

Comment: HTML5 is a W3C standard due to be implemented as the core functionality of all the next generation browsers. Silverlight is not, it's a proprietry 3rd party plugin.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to smoothly move images of card faces, you should be able to get away with client-side JavaScript, probably with the assistance of jQuery effects.

Comment: Can I use your jQuery and JS for animating the movement nicely as it would like in Flash ?  My main goal in this project is to gain knowledge and experience in Java or C#

Comment: Yes, you can. [This example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/) isn't quite the same thing, but it's actually doing more than you want, by the look of it.

Answer (score 1):

Hey! Since a Facebook game can be written in Silverlight (check out Facebook's developers guide for the matter), I would recommend to pick Silverlight, and go for those cool animations!

Anyway, whichever language and technology you pick for your client, the really awesome thing to do would be to make a [SOA server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture), and if you have the time, develope multiple clients on multiple platforms. For that, you can use WCF, which should not be too difficult if you know c#. That SOA thing is only an idea, but it leaves the road open for further development, and gives you a few more things you could write or talk about at your finals.

Good luck with the project!

Comment: If I will do well I will proberly develop it maybe for Android,IPhone. If I write the server side in JAVA/C# will I be able to use it as the Server for android/iphone clients?

Comment: @djacobson, is there any good video tutorial about SOAP, from some documentation its looks very intense